# Efficient query for searching a single character from a huge table with 100 fields

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table that has 100 fields. The table has around 1000 records. I want to know whether any field of any record has a character "*" in it. Owning to the large number of fields (100), I want to know how I can form a query to know whether any field in any record has a character "*" in it. I am not supposed to be use dynamic SQL :(

Answer (score 0):

OK, without using dynamic SQL you can build the static SQL you need like this:

```
select 'select pk, ''' || column_name
        || ''' col from mytable where ' 
        || column_name || ' like ''%x%'';'
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

That will output a select statement for each column, which you can then run as a SQL Plus script:

```
select pk, 'PK' col from mytable where PK like '%x%';
select pk, 'COL2' col from mytable where COL2 like '%x%';
select pk, 'COL3' col from mytable where COL3 like '%x%';
```